# slide in animation between landscape and portrait activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a two activity ActivityA and ActivityB. ActivityA is in Portrait mode and ActivityB is in Landscape mode.I want to implement slide animation between this two activity. I tried below code but it is not working.

enter.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate
          android:duration="500"
          android:fromXDelta="100%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%"
          android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:toYDelta="0%" />
   </set>
```

exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

activity code for activity transition

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
```

Comment: This won't work, you have to use GestureDetector

Comment: plz provide some example code

Comment: Did you first add the screen orientation in Manifest?

Comment: Please added the XML for both activities.

Comment: yes i have specified screen orientation for both screen in manifest file